# Как перекодировать строку из utf-8 в cp1251?

Tags: кодировка, перекодировка, erlang

Как в Erlang изменить кодировку строки? Нашёл `unicode:characters_to_binary(Data, InEncoding, OutEncoding) -> Result`, но непонятно, что писать в `OutEncoding`.

Answer (score 0):

```
unicode:characters_to_binary(Data, utf8, latin1).
```

CP1251 является расширением Latin-1 (ISO 8859-1).